# Error: On Activation: Select: Type: Nothing expected, Array,String,Config entry when running specified code in Arma 3

Tags: sqf

So, my issue is whenever I run this code block within a trigger with condition any player,

```
private _all_freedom_units = ["B_FRD_Freedomer_Patrolman_01","B_FRD_Freedomer_Sniper_01", "B_FRD_Freedomer_Exo_1", "B_FRD_Freedomer_Warrior_01", "B_FRD_Freedomer_SEVA_01", "B_FRD_Freedomer_Gaurdian_01", "B_FRD_Freedomer_Seva_II_01"]; 

private _final_pos = [0,0,0]; 
private _position_player = [0, 0, 0]; 
_direction = getDir player; 
if (_direction > 0 and _direction < 90) then {cardinal_direction = "North";}; 
if (_direction > 90 and _direction < 180) then {cardinal_direction = "South";}; 
if (_direction > 180 and _direction < 250) then{cardinal_direction = "South";}; 
if (_direction > 250 and _direction < 359) then{cardinal_direction = "North";}; 
 
_position_player = getPos player; 
_position_player_x =  _position_player select 0; 
_position_player_y =  _position_player select 1; 
 
if (cardinal_direction == "North") then{  
 _random_x = [250, 500] call BIS_fnc_randomInt; 
 _random_y = [250, 500] call BIS_fnc_randomInt; 
 _final_pos set [0 , _position_player_x + 200 + _random_x]; 
 _final_pos set [1 , _position_player_y + 200 + _random_y]; 
}; 
if (cardinal_direction == "South") then{ 
 _random_x = [-250, -500] call BIS_fnc_randomInt; 
 _random_y = [-250, -500] call BIS_fnc_randomInt; 
 _final_pos set [0 , _position_player_x + _random_x]; 
 _final_pos set [1 , _position_player_y + _random_y]; 
}; 
 
_position = _final_pos;    
    
_group_freedom_patrol = createGroup [west, true];   
 
hint str _final_pos select 0; 
 
_random_number = floor random 5;
```

The editor returns with,

```
On Activation: Select: Type Nothing, expected Array,String,Config entry
```

I have a suspicion from similar reports that it's centered around these statements

```
_position_player = getPos player;
_position_player_x =  _position_player select 0;
_position_player_y =  _position_player select 1;
```

Because of the "select" aspect of the error code, but I just started Arma 3 scripting

A similar post recommended dealing with the Condition portion of the Trigger, but the fixes their didn't work. I'm not quite sure what the issue is at this point, as I'm new to Arma 3 scripted.

The big issue here is I'm 90% sure it's an issue with syntax, because if it was logic the trigger would allow me to use the code in the first place. In this case, the built in checks are barring me from running the code, and syntax errors are harder than logic for me.

The code is intended to run properly, grab the first player who enters the trigger, and using the position data and angle it should (this part of the code isn't included as I'm testing in chunks and this chunk isn't working) spawn units in front of the player, min 250 out, heading towards them,

But as I explained previously, the Arma 3 debugger is yelling at me before I can even test the code.

Answer (score 2):

Take this with a grain of salt, I haven't scripted for Arma 3 for quite the time.
I think if the errors comes up in the editor, then it may be because the player may not be defined (makes sense in the editor). You should check that. Either way - to make it multiplayer compatible - you should use the the "thisList" variable to access the list of the objects which are in the trigger area. If this only triggers for players, then you can use "thisList select 0".

[See the passed variables for On Activation in the documentation](https://community.bistudio.com/wiki/Eden_Editor:_Trigger)